# My Guitar's Volume Knob is Stuck on the Pot

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

My volume knob was loose on my guitar, falling off when I flipped it over, so instead of buying a new knob, I had the genius idea to slip some paper in where the knob slides onto the pot, and now it's stuck.

Even worse, I fiddled around with it trying to get it out by turning it farther than it could in both directions, and now my volume pot is loose in the guitar. How do I take out the pot to replace it, or better yet, how do I get the knob off? Thanks in advance!

I know my description is not very descriptive so I have provided a video:

Answer (score 4):

A couple of screwdrivers, at 180degrees to each other, under the base of the knob will do it. Put something, card or suchlike on the scratchplate to protect it, and either turn both drivers gradually, or use them as levers. Do not turn the knob any more, as that will either break the pot or break off the wires attatched to it, and give you more problems. The paper idea isn't a bad one - perhaps less next time? Certainly better than adhesive!

Answer (score 2):

Solved, just used a large plier to get off the knob.

Comment: One plier? I can only get them in pairs!

Comment: @Ken-Just to let you know if your knob becomes loose in the future and the pot has a knurled shaft that is split, you can remedy the problem by using a small slot screwdriver to spread apart the split, but be very careful not to overdo it. It is quite easy to break off one of the halves of the split shaft if you push it to far.